# HyperLink in Webi Report not responding

Tags: hyperlink, cross-browser, business-objects, webi

We can't click or right click the link on the WebI report that usually downloads an Excel sheet, However we can click it when we export the report to PDF format or opening through an Internet Explorer, however Chrome and Edge is not recognizing the link.

Below are the script used for the link

```
=If([Condition_A]="(Unknown)") Then "<a href='"+[File_Location]+"' target=_blank>LINK</a>" Else "<a href='"+[File Location_2]+"' target=_blank>LINK</a>"
```

Please do provide an Solution

Answer (score 1):

I would start to check one option in cell properties.

In SAP BO 4.3 you can click the desired column with hyperlink, then go to the properties (Apperance settings) and change the "Read content as" to Hyperlink. (screen attached). And Save. Then the click on the cell will open a new website.
This option is also available in previous Webi versions.

[image: Cell properties]